# Adapting a 'custom' component to redux-forms?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

Is it possible to adapt a third-party party component to '[redux-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-form)'?

I would like to use '[react-phone-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-input)' with redux-form, so that it matches the lifecycle of the provided fields.

I have tried:

```
renderPhone({value,  input, label, type, id, meta: { touched, error } }) { // Define stateless component to render input and errors
    id = id || input.name;

    return <div className="form-group">
         <label htmlFor={id}>{label}:</label>
         <ReactPhoneInput  defaultCountry={'ca'} onChange={this.handleMyChange}/>            
        {touched && error && <div className="error bg-warning x">{field.meta.error}</div>}
    </div>
}

 handleChange(value) {
     this.setState({
        phone: phone
     });
 }

 render() {
     <Field
       className="form-control"
       label="Phone number"
       name="phone"
       component={this.renderPhone}
       type="phone"/>
 }
```

This results in the phone input field freezing after inputting the first digit. Using ReactPhoneInput with making it part of the redux-form field works, but removes the benefit of react-form for this element.

Is there a way to make an adaptor that would help make this component play nice with redux-form?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of experimentation, it turns out the solution is simply to call the `onChange` function of the `field.input` object:

```
 renderPhone({value,  input, label, type, id, meta: { touched, error } }) { // Define stateless component to render input and errors
    id = id || input.name;

    return <div className="form-group">
         <label htmlFor={id}>{label}:</label>
         <ReactPhoneInput defaultCountry={'ca'} onChange={input.onChange}/>            
        {touched && error && <div className="error bg-warning x">{error}</div>}
    </div>
 }

 render() {
     <Field
       className="form-control"
       label="Phone number"
       name="phone"
       component={this.renderPhone}
       type="phone"/>
 }
```